# awk + remove duplicate lines but ignore lines that begin with #

Tags: awk, fstab

I use the following awk in order to remove duplicate lines from the `/etc/fstab` file on Linux.

The problem that it also removes the lines that start with `#`.

How can I change the `awk` syntax in order to ignore lines starting with `#` in the file?

```
awk '!a[$0]++'  /etc/fstab > /etc/fstab.new
cp /etc/fstab.new /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell AWK to accept lines starting with `#` as well as non-duplicate lines:

```
awk '/^#/ || !a[$0]++' /etc/fstab > /etc/fstab.new
```

If you want to avoid doing this if there are no duplicate lines (per your comments), you can use something like

```
if awk '!/#^/ && a[$0]++ { dup = 1 }; END { exit !dup }' /etc/fstab; then
    awk '/^#/ || !a[$0]++' /etc/fstab > /etc/fstab.new
    copy /etc/fstab.new /etc/fstab
fi
```

but that ends up dong the work twice effectively.

Comment: is it possible to know only if fstab include duplicate lines with awk ? without to create new file , like verification before I change the fstab file

Comment: @salom yes, `awk '/^#/' /etc/fstab` but why? This can deal with them if they exist and ignores them if they don't. There's no reason to check. Also, if you're using a relatively recent version of GNU awk (you probably are if on Linux), you could do the whole thing in a single step using `-i inplace` to edit the original file (so you don't need to copy it afterwards): `awk -iinplace '/^#/ || !a[$0]++'  /etc/fstab`

Comment: sorry maybe I not explained enough , what I mean is that awk need to return the numbers of duplicate line's from the file not only display them , and only if number isnt equal to 0 then activate the awk '/^#/ || !a[$0]++'  /etc/fstab

Comment: @salom what terdon is saying is that the result is the same, whether you check and only de-duplicate if duplicate lines are present, or de-duplicate anyway.

Comment: Stephen , see my update , I wrote the verification , so if we have duplicate lines from /etc/fstab then I will update the fstab file

Comment: @salom instead of adding your solution to your question, you should edit your question to clarify exactly what you want (your question still doesn’t mention the requirement to only de-duplicate if necessary), and perhaps add your version as another answer.

Comment: OK I will delete it you right